# Nas/Switch/ DD-WRT Router, Interesting Problem

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, lan

I had a network setup that consisted of the following.
WNR2200 [router] with DDWRT [Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (06/23/14) std] running on it, connected to a Netgear 8p Gigabit [Switch].

My laptop and N54l Microserver were connected to the Netgear, then uplinked back to the router which is the DHCP Server .

I moved house, then reconfigured the N54L / Laptop to connect directly to the router at 100mb/s.

The Router itself could ping the N54l from the built in console, but PC could not even find its IP/DNS Name, "Host not found". I could find all other devices on the lan, another Win8 laptop, several android devices etc.
I replace the router with a Netgear DG834GT std, factory settings, and the Laptop could now ping the N54L again, by ip or DNS Name. Again 100mb/s.

I have spent all day trying to figure it out, even reset the DDWRT Router to factory, 30 second Pin reset,twice.

I have now managed to get it working again. I plugged the 8 port Netgear switch back in and connected both the laptop and N54l to it. The Laptop now sees the N54l again!

Rather than move on I'd really like to know why this is happening so by deduction, can you help me figure this out. 
I bamboozled by the thing!

Comment: This is not really about *nix but about networking in general. I am moving it to [su].

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of a dead port on the router? Did you try different ports on the device?

Comment: All ports functioning correctly. I just ran a ping, and plugged into each port on the router in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

By default DD-WRT sets each ethernet port as a unique switch.  You were able to communicate between devices connected to the netgear switch, but not between devices connected on different lan ports on the DD-WRT router

to confirm this run:

```
swconfig list
```

output should be similar to

```
Found: switch0 - eth0 . (wan port)
Found: switch0 - eth1 . (lan ports)
```

run the following to allow wired ports to talk to each other:

```
swconfig dev eth1 set enable_vlan 1
swconfig dev eth1 set apply
```

where eth1 is the wired ports, replace as necessary if you've modified the config.
You'll need to run this from the administration - commands menu in the router administration if you want it to persist upon reboot